# AD CS template security for individual accounts vs security groups

Tags: ca

We have an Enterprise CA and a machine certificate template. Machine was added to proper security group,but we can't wait this machine to reboot in order to enroll certificate and we'r looking for some hints.

If I add this machine account to certificate template security permission directly will it help to enroll certificate more quickly?
What kind of issues can I expect if I would use an individual security permissions on machine certificate template instead of using security group for such machines or both type of permission at the same time?